# Errors with Ruby and File.open

Tags: ruby, file

Having problems with a Ruby script that uses File.Open

Here is the code that I am speaking of...

f = File.open(Socket.gethostname().gsub!(/[[:space:].]/,"")+".log","a")

The issue is the + inside of .open, it is returning a error message saying its a undefined method.

Anyone able to help?

Edit:
Here is some code from the class which is causing the problem.

Not sure if this will help though.

```
def logExecution()
  f = File.open(Socket.gethostname().gsub!(/[[:space:].]/,"")+".log","a")
  f.puts(" [" + Time.new().to_s() + "] " +\
         File.basename($0) + " " + $*.join(" "))
  f.close
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the error message you're getting:     `NoMethodError: undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass` ?

If yes, `then Socket.gethostname().gsub!(/[[:space:].]/,"")` is returning nil

How do you create your Socket ? You could try with a fully qualified domain name, i.e. "myhost.mydomain.com" instead of "myhost".

What name should your log file have ?

Comment: Am guessing this mean its something to do with the way am trying to run the application?

Comment: Could be, or an issue in the application code. Can you come with more details, perhaps more code ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no really compelling reason to strip dots from hostnames.  "www.example.com.log" is a better filename than "wwwexamplecom.log".  So my recommendation would be to use this:

```
def log_execution
  hostname = (Socket.gethostname() || "localhost")
  File.open(hostname + ".log", "a") do |f|
    f.puts(
      " [" + Time.new.to_s + "] " +
      File.basename($0) + " " + $*.join(" ")
    )
  end
end
```

But if you really must, then use this:

```
def log_execution
  hostname = (Socket.gethostname() || "localhost")
  File.open(hostname.gsub(".", "") + ".log", "a") do |f|
    f.puts(
      " [" + Time.new.to_s + "] " +
      File.basename($0) + " " + $*.join(" ")
    )
  end
end
```

Essentially, this block of code just logs the name of the command being run and the command line arguments used to invoke it.  Also note, I renamed and reformatted the method to use standard Ruby coding style.  The original was really awful.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than the ruby code style that you can improve:

- use gethostbyname, and rescue to a default
- open the file using a block, ensures that if something throws, the file is closed

The result would be:

```
require 'socket'

def log_execution()
  logname = Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first rescue "localhost"
  File.open("#{logname}.log", 'a') do |f|
    f.puts(" [" + Time.new().to_s() + "] " + File.basename($0) + " " + $*.join(" "))
  end
end
```

And then you can improve further, by not reinventing the stdlib:

```
require 'socket'
require 'logger'

# do only once in your program
logname = Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first rescue "localhost"
log = Logger.new(logname)
log.level = Logger::WARN
```

Then just log using the standard api:

```
log.info("hello!")
log.warn("message!")
```

If you don't like the format which looks like:

```
W, [2009-12-05T03:05:48.764552 #22759]  WARN -- : message!
```

You can use [log4r](http://log4r.sourceforge.net/), which is api compatible but has more options...